# How to get the length or the width of a percentage of a canvas?

Tags: geometry

I am currently working with the following diagram:

[image]

I know the width and height of the original canvas. How can I figure out the width `s_w` and height `s_h` of 5% of its overall area?

Comment: Do you want the small area to be $5\%$ of the area of the large one, or $5\%$ in each dimension.  Is the small area supposed to be square?  If so, why are we given two dimensions?  If the area is supposed to be $5\%$ of the large one, what is the area of the large one?  What does that make the area of the small one?

Comment: The small one's area needs to be 5% of the area of the overall canvas. The small area is a rectangle.  The area of the large one is 100% and 5% of that is the area of the small one

Comment: That gets the area of the small one, but you have no way to determine its height or width.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the smaller rectangle is $s_{w}\cdot s_{h}$, therefore it is $\dfrac{100\cdot s_{w}\cdot s_{h}}{20\cdot 30}\%$ of the total area. If you want this percentage to be $5$ then you need that $\dfrac{100\cdot s_{w}\cdot s_{h}}{20\cdot 30}=5$, so $s_{w}\cdot s_{h}=30$.

Here you have infinitely many possibilities, for example $s_{w}=5$ and $s_{h}=6$, $s_{w}=3$ and $s_{h}=10$, etc. However, if you want that the smallest rectangle is a square then $s_{w}=s_{h}=\sqrt{30}\approx 5.48$.

Comment: How about if I want to find 1 side of the small rectangle?

Comment: There are infinitely many small rectangles that cover $5\%$ of the total area, so what do you mean by finding 1 side of "the" small rectangle?

Comment: Wouldn't 5% of the canvas length and 5% of the canvas height give me a rectangle with an area that is 5% of the canvas area?

Comment: No, that would produce a rectangle with area that is $5\%\cdot 5\%=0.25\%$ of the canvas area

Comment: If I know the canvas area, can I generate 2 new values for the width and the height of the smaller rectangle?

Comment: @oo92 As Ross & Matías have said, there's not enough info to give a specific unique solution. But if you want the small rectangle to be a specific shape, eg $s_w/s_h=w/h$, then we can give a unique solution.

Comment: Here is a better question. So I know 5% of a canvas and lets just say it is 4000.  If I have a separate rectangular image, how can I resize that image to have the area 4000 while maintaining its aspect ratio?

Comment: That is exactly what PM 2Ring said, in this case $s_{w}/s_{h}=w/h$. In this case the aspect ratio is $30/20$ so for the smaller rectangle to have the same aspect ratio the sides must be $s_{w}=3\sqrt{5}\approx 6.7$ and $s_{h}=2\sqrt{5}\approx 4.47$.